# Are there shortcut keys to run the previous (latest) run-configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, to run with a specific configuration, I always have to click the arrow next to the run icon and choose the desired config.

Is there some keyboard shortcut to either

- run the latest (previously run) config
- or choose a config by the number listed before the config's name?

Thanks